# Can we deploy only bin dlls for SAP Crystal Report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We have a .net WebApplication, that doesn't need to install anything on the release server (only bin dlls needed). The problem is we are not finding a real solution avoiding Crystal Report Runtime installation: seems that the only way is installing runtime.

The application is builded for "AnyCPU" and so CR needs x86 and x64 runtime if we want to dynamically change IIS pool from 32bit to 64bit and viceversa. This is frustrating.

Does exist a way to do that only with CR dlls in bin? We have a lot of reports and change report engine (for example to Telerik or RDLC) will take too much time (and we have already lost enough).

CR version is the last one (2020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice from SAP over the last ~8 years has been consistent: Must install the Crystal Runtime. And should set the app to target 32 or 64-bit (not AnyCPU).

Technically, there might be ways around this but you would be asking for trouble.